# How do I use list indices to return columns of data instead of rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, treeview

I have a table full of data and I'm trying to get the 0th column of it into a Treeview.
This is the code I'm using

```
# Query the database
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM addresses")
    records = c.fetchall()
    result_list = [records[0] for record in records]

# Add Data
    my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid='PLACEHOLDER', text="", values=(result_list, 1, 2, 3, 1000))
```

When I do this it returns my entire 0th row of data, instead of my 0th column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `result_list = [record[0] for record in records]` instead.

Also better just SELECT the required column in the SQL statement to reduce memory usage.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What's the best way to fetch the first column of the first row instead?

Comment: Use the field name of the first column of the table in the SELECT statement.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask how to get just the first column and just the first row. SELECT player1 FROM addresses returns the entire column instead of just the first row of the column

Comment: SELECT player1 FROM addresses LIMIT 1.